# render a partialview from another area, MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to  access a view from another area from the index(herein in blue) by doing

```
@Html.Partial("_search", new {area="hotels"})
```

The rendered view is the one in the root, and my question is how can I render the view in the area hotels.

Thanks

[image: Project files]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the full path to your view.

```
@Html.Partial("~/Areas/hotels/Views/Home/_search.cshtml");
```